# set country code in url and rewrite it with country code

Tags: javascript, php

I want to set country code in url by user IP address and rewrite and redirect `index2.php` with country code.

The `index.php` file:

```
<?php
function getLocationInfoByIp(){
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result  = array('country'=>'', 'city'=>'');
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $client;
    }elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $forward;
    }else{
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    $ip_data = @json_decode
    (file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));    
    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null){
        $result['country'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
    }
    return $result;
}    
$result = getLocationInfoByIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);    
$cont = $result['country'];    
?>
```

The `index2.php` file:

```
<h1>HELLO WORLD !</h1>
```

how can I rewrite the url and redirect in `index2.php`?

When redirect my url should looks like `orchidkart.com/IN/index2.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
header('Location: index2.php?country='.$cont);
```

OR Full path

```
header('Location: http://localhost/directory/index2.php?country='.$cont);
```

OR parse dynamic variables in url

```
header('Location: http://localhost/directory/$cont/index2.php');
```